# Topological objects associated to Steinerberger's 4-regular graphs

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, graph-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology

Very recently, in [arXiv:2008.01153](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.01153), Steinerberger has associated to any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of distinct real numbers a 4-regular graph.

In the case irrational multiples, like $x_n=n\sqrt{2} \pmod{1}$, the plots in $\mathbb{R}^2$ seem to show the projection of a certain genus-g surface (see page 2 of the preprint). [**edit**:06-sept-2020: I had written that these were plots in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is actually not the case, apologies.]

> is that indeed the case, i.e. does a limit shape as $n$ goes to infinity exist ? What type of literature (e.g. keywords, theorems) one should be looking at to establish it ?

Comment: Isn't the paper saying that these surfaces are generated by the "van der Corpus sequence" rather than anything with $\sqrt 2$?

Comment: For the plots shown, yes, but it is written that it also happens for these other sequences. I am intertested by any sequence producing a limit space with that construction.

Comment: @ThomasSauvaget I think Béart answer points to the right field. More specifically, I think the area where graph theory intersects with differential topology is relevant for you. Not directly related, but to give you an idea of this area and the machinery/techniques, look at the references in this post https://mathoverflow.net/q/368129/161328

Comment: How do you embed the graph in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @AntoineLabelle : thanks for the question, I now realise that these are actually plots of the graph in the plane (I'll edit the question). It still suggests that this is the projection of some higher dimensional manifold.

Comment: @ThomasSauvaget I still don't get how you canonically embed the graph in the plane.

Answer (score 5):

The Steinerberger article seems to be aimed at tests about randomness. The question you are raising, which is given as an initial observation in this article, is a topic in topological graph theory.

> The following link should give you helpful references for your question: [Reference for topological graph theory (research / problem-oriented)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365925/161287) .

Comment: Yes, I actually work in stats and was curious about the randomness test, but the geometric plot is hard to ignore. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short Mathematica script that computes the graph and plots it with some standard function

```
f[n_] := Mod[n * Sqrt[2]//N, 1];

n = 200;
seq = f /@ Range[1,n];
map = PositionIndex[seq];
sort = map[#][[1]] & /@ (Sort@seq);

edge1 = Partition[Range[1,n], 2, 1] ~ Join ~ {{n,1}};
edge2 = Partition[sort, 2, 1] ~ Join ~ {{sort[[-1]], sort[[1]]}};
G = Graph[Join[edge1, edge2]]
```

[image]

```
GraphPlot3D[G, GraphLayout->"SpectralEmbedding"]
```

[image]

```
GraphPlot3D[G, GraphLayout->"SpringElectricalEmbedding"]
```

[image]

It seems to resemble some kind of genus 1 surface.

---

But seems to have nothing to do with $\sqrt2$. If I replace $\sqrt 2$ with $\pi$, the result still looks like a torus:

[image]

Apparently, all we need is that the number is irrational.

Comment: Thanks for this code and plots, food for thought!